# Android gesture effect

Tags: android

How do I have a gesture effect like the official calendar app?

Answer (score 1):

Qorry, your question is a little bit strange!

What is a gesture effect? I think that nobody here understand what you mean.

If you are talking about the swipe action that allos to navigate between every month, use this:

Use this method:

```
class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
}
```

You can implement something like that (maube use Y instead of X)

```
private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;


if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideLeftIn);
viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideLeftOut);
viewFlipper.showNext();
} else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideRightIn);
viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideRightOut);
viewFlipper.showPrevious();
```

}